# Cocos2d - CCMenu with multiple buttons calls wrong selector on first load

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Here's an interesting dilemma.  I have two CCMenus being loaded on a page, each with two CCMenuItemImages as buttons.  All four buttons call the same function, which decides what to do using a switch statement that goes off the caller's tag value.

The four buttons are start, tutorial, options, and credits.  I have them split into two menus so that I can horizontally and vertically align them in a faux grid.  This layer is the main menu layer, so it is the first thing to load after the game starts.

The problem is that when the game first loads, pressing *any* button will call the "options" button.  Not just the function, pressing any button on the menu **activates the options button's selected state**.  If I press "start," for instance, the start button's selected state (a glow around the image) doesn't work–the options button glows instead.

Once I get into the options menu, and then back out of it, the main menu works as expected, with each button activating its requisite function.

I should note that I've also run a clean, and removed the app from both the simulator and my iPhone and rebuilt it.

Here's my .h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Constants.h"
#import "GameManager.h"

@interface MainMenuLayer : CCLayer {
    CCMenu *mainMenuTop;
    CCMenu *mainMenuBottom;
}
@end
```

And this is my .m:

```
#import "MainMenuLayer.h"

// Private methods
@interface MainMenuLayer()
- (void)displayMainMenu;
@end

@implementation MainMenuLayer

- (void)playScene:(CCMenuItemFont*) itemPassedIn {
    if ([itemPassedIn tag] == 1) {
        CCLOG(@"Tag 1 found, Scene 1");
        [[GameManager sharedGameManager] runSceneWithID:kGameplayScene];
    } else if ([itemPassedIn tag] == 2) {
        CCLOG(@"Tag was: %d", [itemPassedIn tag]);
        CCLOG(@"Placeholder for next chapters");
    } else if ([itemPassedIn tag] == 3) {
        CCLOG(@"Tag 3, Options");
        [[GameManager sharedGameManager] runSceneWithID:kOptionsScene]; 
    } else if ([itemPassedIn tag] == 4) {
        CCLOG(@"Tag 4, Credits");        
        [[GameManager sharedGameManager] runSceneWithID:kCreditsScene];
    }
}

- (void)displayMainMenu {
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    // Main Menu Top Layer Buttons
    CCMenuItemImage *playGameButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"button-start-up.png" selectedImage:@"button-start-down.png" disabledImage:nil target:self selector:@selector(playScene:)];
    [playGameButton setTag:1];

    CCMenuItemImage *tutorialButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"button-tutorial-up.png" selectedImage:@"button-tutorial-down.png" disabledImage:nil target:self selector:@selector(playScene:)];
    [tutorialButton setTag:2];

    // Main Menu Bottom Layer Buttons
    CCMenuItemImage *optionsButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"button-options-up.png" selectedImage:@"button-options-down.png" disabledImage:nil target:self selector:@selector(playScene:)];
    [optionsButton setTag:3];

    CCMenuItemImage *creditsButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"button-credits-up.png" selectedImage:@"button-credits-down.png" disabledImage:nil target:self selector:@selector(playScene:)];
    [creditsButton setTag:4];

    mainMenuTop = [CCMenu menuWithItems:playGameButton,tutorialButton,nil];
    mainMenuBottom = [CCMenu menuWithItems:optionsButton,creditsButton,nil];

    [mainMenuTop alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding: 10.0f];
    [mainMenuTop setPosition: ccp(winSize.width/2, -500)];
    [mainMenuBottom alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding:10.0f];
    [mainMenuBottom setPosition:ccp(winSize.width/2, -600)];

    id moveActionTop = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5f position:ccp(winSize.width/2, 150)];
    id moveEffectTop = [CCEaseIn actionWithAction:moveActionTop rate:1.0f];
    [mainMenuTop runAction:moveEffectTop];
    [self addChild:mainMenuTop z:2 tag:kMainMenuTagValue];

    id moveActionBottom = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5f position:ccp(winSize.width/2, 75)];
    id moveEffectBottom = [CCEaseIn actionWithAction:moveActionBottom rate:1.0f];
    [mainMenuBottom runAction:moveEffectBottom];
    [self addChild:mainMenuBottom z:3 tag:kMainMenuBottomTagValue];
}

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {        
        [self displayMainMenu];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: very fishy indeed.. could it be that your "CCMenuItemFont* argument for playScene is messing things up (shouldn't it be CCMenuItemImage* anyway)?  Or you can try this: -(void)playScene:(id) sender { if([sender tag] == 1 ..}

Comment: Semantically that makes more sense, and I have changed it.  Sadly, it doesn't solve the problem =/

Comment: Adding all of the CCMenuItemImages to a single CCMenu seems to fix the problem, but that doesn't help the "grid" alignment issue I was trying to solve in the first place.  Is there a way to align CCMenu items both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: ahh... or you can simply just have a different function for each button:) no tags required.. good to get it working first, then look for ways to tidy up/optimize your code later!

Comment: didn't see your last comment. I believe you can position and run actions on individual menu buttons.. Set menu.position = ccp(0,0), then manually position your menu buttons outside the screen as appropriate, and run your button actions.

Comment: Why not try find a solution for aligning the menu items on a grid? I've done it before by tweaking the CCMenu code just a bit, and there's also this answer here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340988/aligning-ccmenu-to-a-grid

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just positioning things manually.  I tried to use the method linked by LearnCocos2D, but I couldn't determine how to make it work properly; the items didn't end up in a proper grid.