# Trying to increase size of CCMenuItemImage in CCMenu

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

I am making a level select screen and have 9 different levels. I have already arranged them in a 3 by 3 formation using CCMenu and it works fine, but they're pretty small buttons and I would like to increase them by about 2 or 3 times. The problem is, when I increase their size, they start overlapping instead of recognizing that they are bigger and spacing them accordingly. Below is my the applicable code and a screenshot of my simulator. I am hoping to just increase the size of each menu item and make the same 3 by 3 structure.

```
CCMenuItemImage * menuItem1 = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"number1_button.png"
                                                         selectedImage: @"number1_button_selected.png"
                                                                target:self
                                                              selector:@selector(doSomethingOne:)];

CCMenuItemImage * menuItem2 = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"number2_button.png"
                                                         selectedImage: @"number2_button_selected.png"
                                                                target:self
                                                              selector:@selector(doSomethingTwo:)]

....

CCMenuItemImage * menuItem9 = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"number9_button.png"
                                                         selectedImage: @"number9_button_selected.png"
                                                                target:self
                                                              selector:@selector(doSomethingNine:)];

CCMenu * myMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuItem1, menuItem2, menuItem3, menuItem4, menuItem5, menuItem6, menuItem7, menuItem8, menuItem9, nil];
myMenu.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width/2, self.contentSize.height/2);

NSNumber* numberOfColumns = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:3];
[myMenu alignItemsInColumns:numberOfColumns,numberOfColumns,numberOfColumns, nil];

[menuItem1 setScale:2];
[menuItem2 setScale:2];
[menuItem3 setScale:2];
[menuItem4 setScale:2];
[menuItem5 setScale:2];
[menuItem6 setScale:2];
[menuItem7 setScale:2];
[menuItem8 setScale:2];
[menuItem9 setScale:2];

[self addChild:myMenu];
```

[image]

Comment: This looks promising...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340988/aligning-ccmenu-to-a-grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  try this code:

   NSNumber* numberOfColumns = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:3];
   [myMenu alignItemsInColumns:numberOfColumns,numberOfColumns,numberOfColumns, nil];

   NSNumber* numberOfRows = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:3];
   [myMenu alignItemsInRows:numberOfRows,numberOfRows,numberOfRows, nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to simply increase the size of the images you're using as the menu item images.

If you're concerned about bundle size you may be better off making a tappable sprite rather than using CCMenu. Then you can align the buttons freely, and use one background image for all buttons together with a custom label node.